# Excel 2007 Advanced Filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to filter multiple columns with dates.  For example, I have 7 rows of names and the columns contain the dates they had office visits.  So I want to be able to see the visits that occurred in a specific month.  For example, I want all the visits to show that occurred in June which are listed in multiple columns.

Column A would have the name, Column B-E have other data about this person, Column F-I each have dates.  If any cell in Column F-I contains a date falling in the specified month, I want the filter to show only those rows.

Can I do this with an advanced Excel Filter?  If not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with Advanced Filtering.

First, make sure your columns (even the dates) have unique headers (see image below). The yellow cell contains a formula that serves as the Criteria for the Advanced Filter:

```
=OR(MONTH(F6)=$B$2,MONTH(G6)=$B$2,MONTH(H6)=$B$2,MONTH(I6)=$B$2)
```

It returns `TRUE` if a row contains a date whose month is equal to the month number entered in **$B$2**. You can use custom number formats and conditional formatting to make this appear in "mmmm" format. You could also modify the formula above to take the name of a month instead of its number -- perhaps something like this:

```
=OR(TEXT(F6,"mmmm")=$B$2,TEXT(G6,"mmmm")=$B$2,TEXT(H6,"mmmm")=$B$2,TEXT(I6,"mmmm")=$B$2)
```

where **$B$2** contains a validation list from which the user can select "January", "February"..."December".

In both formulas, **F6**, **G6**, **H6** and **I6** point to the *first* values in the date columns. These must be ***relative*** cell references in order for the filter to work.

[image]

Make sure that the Criteria cell (yellow) has an empty cell above it. To run the filter:

1. Select your data table.
2. Go to **Data** > **Advanced**
3. Select **Filter the list, in-place**
4. Make sure that **List range** contains the reference to your data table (including headers).
5. For **Criteria range**, select the Criteria cell (yellow in my example) **AND** the empty cell above it.

[image]

After running the filter, I get this:

[image]

Comment: This works great and is a really awesome answer! Thank you Kaze.  I appreciate it.